# submit form to new tab and close modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I am submitting a form to a new tab from a modal window. I want the form to submit, the modal to close, and the parent of the modal to refresh. The new tab opens fine and the modal does not close. I am using this same js in a modal php script with RefWin() as the last line and when the script ends, the modal closes and the parent refreshes. The modal window is a jquery plugin and I do want to use javascript to close the modal. I have attempted using onsubmit and onclick and neither work. I know there is a simple answer to this and I am stumped... appreciate some assistance.

```
<script>

    function reloadSource() {
    var p_ref=parent.location.href;
    parent.location.href=(p_ref);
    }

    function RefWin() {
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
    reloadSource();
    }

</script>


<form action="https://www.paygate.com/p/" method="POST" target="_new" onsubmit="RefWin();">

<input type="text" name="v1" maxlength="200" value="100.00" />


<input type="text" name="v2" maxlength="200" value="Software" />

<input type="image" name="submit" src="http://www.myurl.com/img/paybutton.gif" border="0" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using 
    `$('.modal').remove();`
Where '.modal' is the class of your modal

Comment: No that didn't work and also tried window.close instead of remove. As I mentioned above, the javascript I have closes the modal and refreshes the parent when used as the last script in a php file. Just have not been able to figure out how to make it work with a form submit.